# Swing Layout Ideas

Tags: java, jframe

I'm trying to create a JFrame in java.

The thing is that I can not find the way to do what I want, If I get to put a textField I can not put the button, and it with all the items...

The thing that I want to do is like the model of the image :

[image: Swing Layout]

I appreciate all of your answers, please I need it.

Comment: Post the code you have.

Comment: Can you attempt a solution and then post the code that you're working with/stuck on?

Comment: @Johan Really ... suggesting an absolute layout ? Shame comments cannot be downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is a picture of a [Swing nested layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Your [Swing components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) would be arranged like this.

```
JFrame
    JPanel - main panel, Box layout, Page axis
        JPanel - drawing panel
        JScrollPane
            JTextArea
        JPanel - Flow Layout
            JTextField
            JButton
```

Your drawing panel would be defined with a preferred size the same as the image size.  You draw the image directly on the JPanel by overriding the paintComponent method.

### Edited to add some example code.

Here's the layout I created based on the outline you gave.

[image: Swing Layout]

I have no idea what this GUI is supposed to do, so this is a skeleton of a Swing GUI.

I use the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) whenever I create a Swing GUI.  This allows me to separate my concerns and create complex GUIs without encountering too many problems.

The first class I created is the LayoutDemo class.

```
package com.ggl.layout;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.layout.model.LayoutModel;
import com.ggl.layout.view.LayoutFrame;

public class LayoutDemo implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new LayoutFrame(new LayoutModel());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LayoutDemo());
    }

}
```

This 20 line class does 3 important things.

1. Puts the creation and use of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) by executing the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  **You must do this when creating a Swing application.**
2. Instantiates the LayoutModel class.
3. Instantiates the LayoutFrame class.

Next, we'll take a look at the LayoutModel class.

```
package com.ggl.layout.model;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class LayoutModel {

    private Document document;

    private String textString;

    public LayoutModel() {
        document = new DefaultStyledDocument();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }

    public Document getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public String getTextString() {
        return textString;
    }

    public void setTextString(String textString) {
        this.textString = textString;
    }

}
```

Since I don't know what this GUI is supposed to do, this class contains the Document for the JTextArea and the String for the JTextField.  I'm assuming that the String will be added to the Document, and that something will be drawn on the drawing area.  The data for the drawings will be kept in the model class.

Next, let's take a look at the LayoutFrame class.

```
package com.ggl.layout.view;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.layout.model.LayoutModel;

public class LayoutFrame {

    private ControlPanel controlPanel;

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private JFrame frame;

    private LayoutModel model;

    private TextPanel textPanel;

    public LayoutFrame(LayoutModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Swing Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
        mainPanel.add(drawingPanel);

        textPanel = new TextPanel(model);
        mainPanel.add(textPanel.getScrollPane());

        controlPanel = new ControlPanel(model);
        mainPanel.add(controlPanel.getPanel());

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(controlPanel.getSubmitButton());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void exitProcedure() {
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

This class puts the JPanels in the JFrame in the createPartControl method.

We use Swing components.  We do not extend Swing components.  The only time we extend a Swing component, or any other Java class, is when we want to override one of the component methods.  We'll see an example of that when we discuss the drawing panel.

Next, we'll look at the DrawingPanel class.

```
package com.ggl.layout.view;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.layout.model.LayoutModel;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6305888561097318682L;

    private LayoutModel model;

    public DrawingPanel(LayoutModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.setPreferredSize(model.getPreferredSize());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}
```

We set the size of the DrawingPanel, and we paint whatever it is we're going to paint in the paintComponent method.  The call to super.paintComponent must be the first line in the overridden method.

Since we're overriding the paintComponent method, we extend a JPanel. We add a serialVersionUID because JPanel implements the Serializable interface.  This interface requires a serialVersionUID.  The serialVersionUID should be changed every time you add or remove Swing components from the JPanel.

Next, let's look at the TextPanel class.

```
package com.ggl.layout.view;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import com.ggl.layout.model.LayoutModel;

public class TextPanel {

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    private JTextArea textArea;

    private LayoutModel model;

    public TextPanel(LayoutModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 60);
        textArea.setDocument(model.getDocument());
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    }

    public JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

}
```

This class puts a JTextArea inside a JScrollFrame.  The scroll bars do not appear unless there is more than the 10 lines of 60 characters per line that we defined the JTextArea with.

The Document that holds the text of the JTextArea is kept in the model class.  The text added to the Document would be passed to the Document through a method in the model class.

Finally, let's look at the ControlPanel class.

```
package com.ggl.layout.view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.ggl.layout.model.LayoutModel;

public class ControlPanel {

    private JButton submitButton;

    private JPanel panel;

    private JTextField textField;

    private LayoutModel model;

    public ControlPanel(LayoutModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.addActionListener(new SubmitActionListener());
        panel.add(submitButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    public JButton getSubmitButton() {
        return submitButton;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public class SubmitActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            model.setTextString(textField.getText().trim());
        }

    }

}
```

This class contains a JTextField and a JButton.  I used the BorderLayout so that I could stretch the JTextField to fill the main JPanel.

The JButton has a controller class, SubmitActionListener, attached.  When the JButton is clicked, or the Enter key is pressed, the controller code is executed.

Thanks for reading this far.  This code can be the basis for almost any Swing GUI.

Comment: Can you give me a little example of this with code?

Comment: @Jaume Riera: I could, but it wouldn't be little.  It would be a model class, a JFrame class, and 3 JPanel classes.

Comment: Will it take a lot of time to do this example for me? I don't want to disturb anybody but I'm new on this and I need it, to start my project....

Comment: @Jaume Riera: I updated my answer with example code.  Be sure that you understand what I did, and not just copy the code into your project.

Comment: Thank you so much Gilbert, I'm gonna take a look! You are the best.

Comment: I have 2 errors, `controlPanel = new ControlPanel(model);
        mainPanel.add(controlPanel.getPanel());` cannot resolve getPanel() method and `frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(controlPanel.getSubmitButton());` cannot resolve getSubmitButton() method

Comment: @Jaume Riera: The getPanel and getSubmitButton methods are in the ControlPanel class in the answer.  You need to learn some basic debugging, or you will not be able to add any code to my Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use multiple `layout` on the same `Frame` which will allow you to position all the item as you want it.

You can position a lot of the `layouts` using [SwingConstants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html) see

There is serveral layout you can use :

- [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)
- [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html)
- [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)
- [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html)
- [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)
- [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html)
- [SprintLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html)

which gives you way enought possibilities. See the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on each of the `layouts`. You should then be able to position all your components easily.

Comment: @JaumeRiera at the bottom of the page of the links I posted for the layouts, if you click next and follow the tutorial there are many examples.